# How can I access the fields in a JDialog of another app?

Tags: java, swing, winapi, java-native-interface, awt

I need to fill out some fields in a JDialog of another Java app. I don't have access to its source code. I've done this before for regular Windows apps using WinAPI. However, this is a Java app I'm targeting. So far, I've been able to get the window handle using JNI + winapi/findWindows.

Is it possible to write a Java program that instantiates a JDialog from a winapi window handle (hwnd)?

Something like:

```
HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow("WindowClass", "WindowTitle");
JDialog externalDialog = new JDialog.fromHWND(hwnd);
```

Comment: You're going to find that really hard, as Swing components don't have an individual window handle, they are rendered as part of the parent window component. I'm unaware of any means by which you can do this outside of the JVM. If the dialog is with the same JVM you should be able inspect the components on the containers using a recursive algorithm

Comment: Say that I manage to run both programs in the same JVM. How would I go about filling those text fields?

Comment: Does Swing expose its controls to MSAA or UI Automation (open question)? If so you can just use either (preferably the latter). In fact, if the target program is a Swing program, I wonder if you can just get the AccessibleContext directly instead...

Comment: @andlabs Very interesting suggestion. I had some old C# code that I used to test whether I can get access to those fields via IAccessible. I was able to get some children (title bar, scroll bar, the window itself, etc) but not the text fields.

Comment: You can use the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) tool to verify, whether the GUI is exposed to UI Automation/MSAA.

Comment: I've been able to confirm using Inspect that indeed, only a few controls are exposed via IAccessible. The fields I want to edit are not.